# SelectList not populated using ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, viewbag

This piece of code is puzzling me, looks like im missing something.

**Model**

```
public class County
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Education
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ListOfCounties = new SelectList(db.Counties, "ID", "Name");
    ViewBag.ListOfEducations = new SelectList(db.Educations, "ID", "Title");

    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Person.County, ViewBag.ListOfCounties as SelectList, "Choose county")
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Person.Education, ViewBag.ListOfEducations as SelectList, "Choose education")
```

The list of counties are rendered normally, but the list of educations is blank.
The difference is that I use "Title" not "Name" in "Educations".

I then tried renaming "Title" to "Name" in my model and controller, and then the list rendered normally.

But I would like to use "Title" not "Name"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this, in my controller I changed it to.

```
ViewBag.ListOfEducations = new SelectList(db.Educations.Select(c => new { c.ID, c.Title }), "ID", "Title");
```

But why did I have to do this? In my oppinion the initial code should have worked.